# Disable Zoom but Preserve Pan in D3 Observable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Working with the [D3 Observable Zoomable Map Tiles](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-map-tiles).

I want to **allow panning**, but **disable zooming**. Is there a way to disable zooming, but keep the ability to pan the visual?

The relevant code is here:

```
 svg
  .call(zoom)
  .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(width >> 1, height >> 1)
    .scale(1 << 12));

function zoomed(transform) {
const tiles = tile(transform);

image = image.data(tiles, d => d).join("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", d => url(...d3.tileWrap(d)))
    .attr("x", ([x]) => (x + tiles.translate[0]) * tiles.scale)
    .attr("y", ([, y]) => (y + tiles.translate[1]) * tiles.scale)
    .attr("width", tiles.scale)
    .attr("height", tiles.scale);
}
```

But the transform seems to combine zooming and panning as a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the extent of a zoom by calling [`scaleExtent`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_scaleExtent) on the zoom behavior. You didn't specify the definition of `zoom` in `svg.call(zoom)` so I've created a definition in the example.

```
const zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 1]);

svg
  .call(zoom)
  .call(
    zoom.transform,
    d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width >> 1, height >> 1).scale(1 << 12)
  );
```